# I need the JobService to wake up every 15 - 20 minutes

Tags: android, kotlin

I need the [JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService) to wake up every 15 - 20 minutes
At the beginning of work the application [JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService) works correctly, but after some time it wakes up after an hour or two hours.
Why does [JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService) work that way?
How to fix it?
Maybe you know any alternatives to [JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService), that can wake up the application every 15 - 20 minutes

```
--------------------------initialization-------------------------------------
jobScheduler = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, ComponentName(this, W2BJobService::class.java))
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)
            .build()
-----------------------------run---------------------------------------------
jobScheduler?.schedule(jobInfo)
```

Comment: I use work manager

Comment: You can go with WorkManager with PeriodicWorkRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job service jobs will get deferred to a later point in time if the OS deems it necessary to preserve battery life.

Job execution is determined by the OS, of the device is sleeping (it not being used with screen off) for periods of time the execution of jobs gets more time inbetween.

See the Doze documentation

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: Thanks. I added setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() and it fixed my problem